# Pipe apache log files - into nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, apache2, apache

So I want to setup a nodejs process to listen and record the log files of my Apache2 server. I know there is a way to 'pipe' the log file to a script, but I cant seem to get it to work.

I have created a file called 'noder' which has the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

var stdin  = process.stdin;
var fs     = require('fs');

stdin.resume();

stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
     fs.writeFileSync('./output.log',chunk.toString());
}).on('end', function () {
     console.log('stdin:closed exiting');
});
```

It simply writes the stdin to a text file.

I also set my httpd.conf setting to the following:

```
CustomLog |/tmp/noder logstash_json
```

- fyi: logstash_json is just a custom format I created, it works logging to a normal file.

I have tried all kinds of different formats in the httpd.conf file and nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After some more working and banding my head on the desk, I finally figured it out:

CustomLog "|/usr/local/bin/node /nodelogger/noder" logstash_json

Thanks,